# impressão de Table HTML

Tags: html, impressão

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação em php com mysql e em um determinado ponto preciso fazer uma consulta no banco e trazer as informações em uma tabela. Até aí tranquilo, porém eu preciso ter a opção de imprimir todo o conteúdo da tabela, ou seja, imprimir (em papel) uma consulta dinâmica.

Estudei sobre ireport mas estou com muita dificuldade, e eu gostaria de saber se existe outra forma de gerar essa impressão ou não. Em outra parte da aplicação eu faço impressão de certificados e é bem tranquilo, mas o ireport me dá impressão que vou ter que fazer umas gambiarras pra usar com php.

Segue um exemplo da tabela que estou utilizando, e lembrando que por vezes a pesquisa gera diversas páginas.

```
 <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" class="display" id="listausers">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>N°Registro</th><th>Beneficiário</th><th>Data Emissão</th><th>CPF</th><th>CNH</th><th>Data do Cadastro</th></th><th>Operações</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody> 
    <?php
    $data_atual=explode("/" , date('d/m/Y'));
    $ano_atual=$data_atual[2];
    $alvara_vaga_idoso = new alvara_vaga_idoso();
    $alvara_vaga_idoso->selecionaTudo($alvara_vaga_idoso);
    while($res = $alvara_vaga_idoso->retornaDados()):
        echo '<tr>';
        printf('<td>%s</td>',$res->num_registro ."/".$ano_atual);
        printf('<td>%s</td>',$res->nome_beneficiario);
        printf('<td>%s</td>',$res->data_emissao);
        printf('<td>%s</td>',$res->cpf);
        printf('<td>%s</td>',$res->cnh);
        printf('<td class="center">%s</td>',date("d/m/Y - H:i:s",strtotime($res->datacad)));

        printf('<td class="center"><a href="?m=alvara_vaga_idoso&t=incluir_alvaras_vaga_idoso" title="Novo Cadastro"> <img src="images/add.png" alt="Novo Cadastro"/> </a> <a href="?m=alvara_vaga_idoso&t=editar_alvara_vaga_idoso&num_registro=%s" title="Editar Cadastro"> <img src="images/edit.png" alt="Editar Cadastro"/> </a></a> <a href="?m=alvara_vaga_idoso&t=visualizar_alvara_vaga_idoso&num_registro=%s" title="Visualizar Cadastro"> <img src="images/view.png" alt="Visualizar Cadastro"/><a href="?m=alvara_vaga_idoso&t=imprimir_alvara_vaga_idoso&num_registro=%s" title="Imprimir Credencial"> <img src="images/printer.png" alt="Imprimir Credencial"/> </a> </td>',$res->num_registro,$res->num_registro,$res->num_registro);
        echo '</tr>';
    endwhile;
    ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Você gera essa tabela em tela, e terá um botão de imprimir, seria isso?

Comment: Isso mesmo Rodrigo, a minha dificuldade é como imprimir quando for mais de uma pagina

Comment: vc gera um tabela com paginação? seria?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Na `head` da sua página coloque:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="print.css" media="print" />
```

Crie o arquivo `print.css` e estilize os elementos da sua tabela da forma que precisa e dê `display:none` nos elementos que você não quer que apareça na página de impressão.

Em seguida crie um botão para impressão na sua página php:

```
echo '<a href="#" onClick="print();">Imprimir</a>';
```

Se preferir colocar uma página de impressão separada, você pode fazer o mesmo processo nela, bastando trocar apenas o código php acima por:

```
echo '<script>print();</script>';
```

E no botão de impressão da página anterior você envia o usuário para essa nova página. São duas formas funcionais.

Comment: Dalton obrigado pela resposta, minha dúvida é se dessa forma irá imprimir todas as paginas da tabela, por exemplo: dependendo da pesquisa gera 3 paginas e dependendo gera 10 paginas

Comment: @mayconrocha eu usei essa solução em um sistema e funcionou para todas as páginas a serem impressas. O que recomendo é que você faça um teste/simulação da solução.

Comment: Muito obrigado Dalton, vou testar aqui

Comment: @mayconrocha, conseguiu?

Comment: Dalton, me desculpe a falta de experiência mas não consegui

Comment: @mayconrocha, o que deu de errado nos testes?

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/27739/discussion-between-dalton-menezes-and-maycon-rocha).